# How to deploy PowerBuilder 10.5 projects?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy

Friends,
I am a vb6 developer. Now I have a requirement to work on PowerBuilder 10.5.
In vb6 I use to deploy the project by just creating an exe or thru the "Package and deployment" wizard to deploy the programs in other computers. Like that, how can I do it in PowerBuilder 10.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose you would make a plain PB app (not a .NET etc.) first you have to do the followings:

1. File/New
2. Project tab
3. select Application wizard (or Applocation project)

After compliting you get a project object. After that open this project file and then click Design/Deploy project. This will make the exe (and dll-s if you have set that way).

After all done you will need the necessary Powrbuilder dll-s also. You can make a package with the Powerbuilder Runtime Packager what is the part of the Powerbuilder installation files (just run it from the start menu). There you can select which features, databases you are using, and the packager will include the necessary dll-s.

After you finished just copy your own application files (exe, dll) and the file what the runtime packager made to the selected computer.

Br. Gábor

Comment: DARKinVADER gave a pretty good summary, except that you have to __install__ the file the Runtime Packager makes. For more detail see the topic "Deployment Techniques" in the Application Techniques book. In recent PB versions this book is in the online help. In older versions the books were a separate install. You can also read them on the Sybase website.